# Proving specific properties of $x_{n+1} = x_n + \frac{1}{nx_n}$ where $x_1 = \frac{1}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, harmonic-numbers

First, I am asked to prove that $(x_n)_{n \geq 1}$ is divergent.

Secondly, I have to find the limit of $\left( \frac{x_n}{\sqrt{2\ln(n)}} \right)_{n \geq 1}$ (if it exists).

What I managed to show:

- $(x_n)_{n \geq 1}$ is monotonically increasing:

$$x_{n+1} - x_n = \frac{1}{nx_n} > 0$$

- $x_{n+1} \geq \frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}$:

$$x_{n+1} = x_n + \frac{1}{nx_n} \geq 2\sqrt{\frac{x_n}{nx_n}} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{n}} \textbf{ (AM-GM) }$$

- $x_{n+1} \leq \frac{1}{2} \left(H_{n}+1 \right)$:

$$ x_{n+1} = x_{n} + \frac{1}{nx_n} \leq x_{n} + \frac{1}{2n} \leq x_{n-1} + \frac{1}{2n} + \frac{1}{2(n-1)} \leq \dots \leq x_1 + \frac{1}{2}H_n = \frac{1}{2} \left( H_n + 1 \right)$$

- $(x_n)_{n \geq 1}$ is divergent:

Suppose the sequence converges with limit $l \in (0, \infty)$. From the last inequality we have:
$$ x_{n+1} \leq \frac{1}{2} \left( H_n + 1 \right) \Leftrightarrow x_{n+1} - \frac{1}{2} \ln(n) \leq \frac{1}{2} \left( H_n - \ln(n) + 1 \right)$$

As $n \to \infty$ the LHS approaches becomes $l - \frac{1}{2} \lim_{n \to \infty} \ln (n)$ which diverges to $- \infty$, but the RHS converges to $\frac{1}{2}(\gamma + 1)$ where $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni Constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_constant), which is a contradiction.

Edit: Thank you everyone for your comments, I now understand how to finish this assingment.

Comment: Hint: $0 \le x_{n+1}^2 - x_n^2 - \frac{2}{n} = \frac{1}{n^2x_n^2} \le \frac{1}{n^2x_1^2}$

Comment: The proof of divergence can be much simpler: if $x_n$ converged, it would converge to a finite, positive limit (say $L$). Then $0<x_n<L$ for all $n$ and you have $x_{n+1}=x_n+\frac{1}{nx_n}>x_n+\frac{1}{nL}$.

Comment: @ChrisLewis, i don't see the contradiction, care to elaborate?

Comment: A simpler proof for divergence:
$$x_{n+1}^2 = x_n^2 + \frac{2}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2 x_n^2 } >x_n^2 + \frac{2}{n}\implies x_{n}^2 > x_1^2 + 2 \underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{n}}_{\text{diverge}}$$

Comment: @MartinR one of us is mistaken, probably me! The idea was to continue that process to find that $x_{n+1}>x_1+\frac{H_n}{L}$. But since $L$ is finite and positive, we can make this as large as we like - in particular, we can find some $N$ such that $x_N>L$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: @ChrisLewis: I misunderstood your argument. You are right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One can apply the [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem):
$$
 \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x_n^2}{2 \ln(n)} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x_{n+1}^2-x_n^2}{2 (\ln(n+1)-\ln(n))}
$$
if the limit on the right exists. But
$$
\frac{x_{n+1}^2-x_n^2}{2 (\ln(n+1)-\ln(n))} = \frac{2/n+ 1/(n^2x_n^2)}{2 \ln(1+1/n)} = \frac{1/n}{\ln(1+1/n)} \left( 
1 + \frac{1}{2n x_n^2} \right)
$$
converges to $1$, since $x_n \to +\infty$ is already known.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly
$$x_{n+1}^2 = x_n^2+\frac2{n} + \frac{1}{n^2x_n^2}\ge x_n^2+\frac2{n}$$
and hence
$$ x_n^2\ge x_1^2+2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac1k=x_1^2+2\ln n+2\gamma+o(1). \tag1$$
On the other hand, it is easy to see
$$ x_n\ge 1, \forall n\ge 2 $$
and hence for $n\ge 2$,
$$x_{n+1}^2 = x_n^2+\frac2{n} + \frac{1}{n^2x_n^2}\le x_n^2+\frac{2}{n}+\frac1{n^2}. $$
From (1) one has, for $\forall n>2$
$$ x_n^2\le x_2^2+2\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k}+\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}\frac1{n^2}=x_2^2+2\ln (n-1)-2+\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}\frac1{n^2}+2\gamma+o(1). \tag2$$
From (1) and (2), one has, for $n>N$,
$$ x_1^2+2\ln n+\gamma+o(1) \le x_n^2\le x_2^2+2\ln (n-1)-2+\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}\frac1{n^2}+2\gamma+o(1). $$
This implies
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n^2}{2\ln n}=1.$$

Answer (score 1):

Replacing the recursion by this simple version of a corresponding ODE

$$\frac{d}{dn} x(n) = \frac{1}{n x(n)}\tag{1}$$

gives the solution

$$x(n) = \pm \sqrt{C+2\log(n)}\tag{2}$$

which coincides with the result striktly derived  by others. This is not likely to be an accident.